# Как очистить сроку по шаблону через preg_replace?

Tags: php

Как очистить строку от слешей в начале и конце, повторяющихся слешей, спецсимволов (кроме -_) и от index в конце?

```
$str = '/test/test/index';   // test/test
$str = 'test/test/';         // test/test
$str = '/test/test';         // test/test
$str = 'test/test/index///'; // test/test
$str = 'test/test///test2';  // test/test/test2
$str = 'test/';              // test
$str = '//////test/';        // test
$str = '/index/test/';       // index/test
$str = '/te&s?t/';           // test

$path = preg_replace('##', '', $str);
```

Comment: это же не сложно. что вы попробовали сделать?

Comment: @splash58 пока как убрать в начале придумал `#^[/]#` но что то не совсем правильно работает

Comment: `~^/+|(?:/index)?/*$~` поменяйте на ничто

Comment: А не значете почему из адреса `http://localhost//test/test/` в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']` у меня выводится `/test/` почему не `//test/test/` ?